# libreoffice - how to store database inside odt document

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-macros

I'm using libreoffice and I have a problem to create a list of data inside an odt document to use for a macro.

I see odt documents can store a database with keys and values, so I want to make a database to store inside the document.

## The problem

I open an odt document and enter inside the data source menu trought `View -> Data sources`, I select `tables` and create a new database with `use wizard to create table`.

After I configure the database keys and select `add data now` I get this error:

[image: error]

The details of the error says this, I'm not using SQL nor I'm an expert about it so I don't know what is referring about.

```
SQL Status: HY000
The query cannot be executed. It contains no valid columns.

The SQL command leading to this error is:
SELECT * FROM "Tasks"
```

**What I'm doing wrong?**

I can't find anything online to solve this problem, all buttons on the database interface are disabled and I can't click anything useful.

How do I make this databse? and how do I access his data from a visual basic macro?

Comment: The language LibreOffice uses is called Basic, which is related to but not the same as Microsoft Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a rule of thumb followed by experienced users of Base: Avoid wizards! Here is what I did:

1. Right-click on *Tables* > *Edit Database File*. *Create Form in Design View*.
2. Column `id` integer, Column `name` varchar
3. Save as `Tasks`. Also, save the Base and Writer files.

Now enter some data in the Data Sources view from Writer.

[image: tasks table]

Finally, here is a macro to display "build proposal" and "submit proposal".

```
oDatabaseContext = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sdb.DatabaseContext")
oDatasource = oDatabaseContext.getByName("Bibliography")
oConnection = oDatasource.GetConnection("","")
oSQL_Statement = oConnection.createStatement()
stSql = "SELECT * FROM ""Tasks"""
oResult = oSQL_Statement.executeQuery(stSql)
While oResult.next
    MsgBox oResult.getString(2)
Wend
```